# Can not do the array equation in php

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to create an array equation where the array value will be equated to the existing sequence, but I can not display it in array..how do I fix it?

```
$ht = array('day' => 1,'day' =>2,'day' =>3,'day' =>4);                          
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    if($x == $ht['day']){
        echo 'x';
    }else{
        echo $x;
    }
}
```

Which I expect `xxxx5678910` but I result `123x45678910`

Comment: Try `var_dump($ht)`… An array cannot have the same key multiple times.

Comment: Put another way, how can the single value `$ht['day']` equal all of `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`…?!

Comment: Just to expand on the above...when you wrote `if($x == $ht['day'])`....which of the four "day" items in your array are you expecting it to reference? How did you think the computer would be able to tell the difference and know which one you mean? It's not logical. You need to give each item in your array a different identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your array :

```
$ht = array('day' => 1,'day' =>2,'day' =>3,'day' =>4);
```

I you just do `var_dump($ht);` you will see that you have :

```
array (size=1)
    'day' => int 4
```

So try this to get what you want :

```
$ht = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4);                          
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    if(!empty($ht[$x])){
        echo 'x';
    }else{
        echo $x;
    }
}
```

Output is : `xxxx5678910`

You have multiple way to achieve it, that's just one among other :)

Answer (score 0):

When u use same key, u overwrite your array key, so at the and u have only one record in your array, u can try something like this:

```
<?php

$ht = array('day1' => 1,'day2' =>2,'day3' =>3,'day4' =>4);
var_dump($ht);                          
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    if (isset($ht['day' . $x])) {
        if($ht['day' . $x] == $x){
            echo 'x';
        } 
    } else{
            echo $x;
        }
}
?>
```

Return :

```
xxxx5678910
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop at all to get the expected output.
You can use range() to create an array with numbers 1 to 10 as in the loop.
Then array_diff finds the numbers not in the $ht array so that they can be echoed with implode.

```
$ht = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4); 
$range = range(1,10);

$diff = array_diff($range, $ht); // [5,6,7,8,9,10]

echo str_repeat("x", count($ht)) . implode("", $diff);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZCU15

---

If the numbers are not always consecutive you can use array_intersect, array_fill and array_flip to create the new array with "x" instead of numbers in $ht array.

Then use array_replace to replace number values with "x" and output with implode.

```
$ht = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 9); 
$range = range(0,10);
unset($range[0]); // unset 0 since you want 1 as lowest
$x = array_intersect_key(array_fill(1,max($ht), "x"), array_flip($ht));
// $x = [1=>"x", 2=>"x", 3 => "x", 9=>"x"]

$new = array_replace($range, $x);

echo implode("", $new);
```

https://3v4l.org/gtSl9